# Active en un for

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, bucle-for

tengo un ciclo for en js que por cada registro me imprime un fragmento de codigo HTML, sin embargo, necesito hacer que uno permanezca activo y los otros 2 no. aquí les dejo un trozo del codigo

```
var tabla2;
function addRow3(datos2) {
    var i = Object.keys(datos2).length;
    for (key in datos2) {
        tabla2 = $('<div class="carousel-item active"><div style="color: #ffffff; text-align: center"><h3>Feliz Cumpleaños</h3></div>');
        $("#carousel2").append(tabla2);
        i++
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar más tu pregunta por favor? "que uno permanezca activo y los otros 2 no" ¿a qué te refieres?

Comment: intento hacer un carrousel pero para que me funcione no debiesen estar todos activos como esta actualmente, uno debiese tener el active y los otros 2 no, y asi (ej. si son 3 datos el primero deberia tener el active y los otros 2 no luego el segundo deberia tener el active pero los otros 2 no, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es activar un elemento con tu clase active, si es el primero se soluciona insertando active en el primero usando una bandera. en cambio si depende de los datos que obtienes del ciclo deberas armar la condicion.

Ejemplo para activar el primero:

```
function addRow3(datos2) {
    let inicio=true;
    let tabla2;
    let i = Object.keys(datos2).length;
    for (key in datos2) {
        tabla2 = '<div class="carousel-item '+((inicio===true)?"active":"")+'"><div style="color: #ffffff; text-align: center"><h3>Feliz Cumpleaños</h3></div>';
        $("#carousel2").append(tabla2);    
        inicio=false;
        i++;
    }
}
```